A question about I2C resistor locations and bus capacitance
When an MCU is communicating with a sensor or DAC:

does it matter where the pull up resistors closer to?
and when calculating the bus capacitance, should always both the sensor and MCU input capacitance be added as part of total bus capacitance? or is this about the proximity of the resistor?


The I2C bus is restricted to a few meters only and common ground potential is required. The total length of the bus is much smaller than a quarter wave length of the clock frequency. So the location of the pull up resistors does not matter. The capacitances of all nodes (both the sensor and MCU input) and the complete cable should be added. Which bus speed do you want to use?

@Uwe The clock may be slow but the falling edges are allowed to be fast, 20ns at 5.5V and proportionally faster at lower voltages. So at 3.3V and sìgnal traveling at 0.66*c in cable, it's less than 2.4 meters. Some buses that are based on I2C also may mandate what value  resistors should be and on which end. You really start to see reflections in the signal shape even on 1 meter cable.

Note that the stock solution [to reflection] is that there is no solution; I2C is a local bus, and using it over distance is an aberration.  Resistor placement doesn't matter because the values are not matched to the line, very little termination value. There are terminated equivalents (DI2C; CANbus in a certain respect), which do use matched resistors, the placement of which matters.

@Justme I2C is not a bus terminated at both ends with a resistor matched to the cable's impedance. The falling edges may be fast, but the rising edges are very slow.

@Uwe Who says it isn't? On many occasions, there are series terminations resistors between bus wire and chip pins. However it is mainly used to slow down the falling edges, if chip output drivers are strong and too fast, but nevertheless may match the impedance when driving the bus. For example in the infamous Access.bus standard.

On short distances the placement of the resistors does not matter. On longer distances (which is not what I2C is for) it is typical to have resistors on the MCU side, although there is no technical reason for this. Think about it this way - there is no electrical difference between the controller and the device circuits in standard specification. If resistor placement affected communication in any way, it won't be reliable bi-directional bus anymore.
It is better to include all capacitance in the calculation, although at the speeds of standard and fast modes you have a lot of leeway. It is only at 1 to 5 Mbps it becomes critical.
As a side note, you can always consider active pull-up if you cannot reduce bus capacitance down to your speed requirements.

Typically, on a plain I2C bus, the bus is assumed to have signal fall (and rise) times so slow, at least compared to the bus length (maybe onboard a PCB or at most between two PCBs close to each other), that the pull-up placement does not matter.
Anyway the placement cannot matter, because any device on bus is allowed to pull data (and clock too on a multimaster system) low anyway, so if there is only one set of pull-ups, it could be at device A or device B or in the middle.
For the purposes of making the calculations simple, the assumption is that there is a single set of pull-ups and even if there are several, they are handled as a simple lumped total pull-up resistance.
For the same reason, the bus capacitance contains just a sum of all the capacitances on the bus as a single lump, including IC pin capacitance, bus wiring capacitance on PCB and other cabling, connectors, and of course, any added filtering capacitance to deliberately slow down the signal edges.
It all becomes a bit more complex quickly, if you have multiple bus segments like through an I2C mux IC, and as each separate bus segment must have a separate set of pull-ups, the calvulations can be simplified again by assuming each segment having some equivalent resistance and capacitance.
So as the fall time of 100 kHz bus can be as fast as possible and 400 kHz bus has a shortest allowed slew of 5.5V in 20 nanoseconds, it can be seen that on cabling longer than 1-2 meters the transmission line effects such as refections start to become an issue with fast edges and they need to be handled by slowing the edges down to an acceptable level.
This is why some bus standards based on I2C such as DDC and standard that use DDC define the pull-up resistor values, pull-up voltage, and the placement of pull-ups and also the capacitance limits allowed for each device and the cable. For example DDC requires that most of the pull-ups in the range of 2k are at host and something like 47k on the device side.
As as much as the I2C standard specifies a limit for slowest possible edges and maximum capacitance, it also allows slowing down the clock to allow handling more capacitance and slower rising edges, with more drive current too. So while the specs are well defined the specs allow you to go outside the specs and that's fine too.
